# Question on circuit function evaluation

Tags: quantum-gate, entanglement, quantum-circuit, superposition

In this question, from what I understand, the circuit on the right hand side can not be evaluated for f(0) so depending on value of y, we will have two different f(0)s so this equality of circuits should not be possible in the first place is what I believe, but it is? I do not understand how, if it is, is it due to some restrictions on the function f itself?.

---

Show that the f-controlled Uf implementation of function evaluation is also equivalent to a C-U˜
f operation. Find U˜
f
[image]

Comment: @MarkS Thank you for your feedback, I have edited the question, I hope it now meets the requirements.